# SQL Server driver installed with OS

Tags: sql-server, odbc

Does the "SQL Server" driver that gets installed with the OS get updated via windows updates? This is the driver that can be select when defining a DSN via ODBC Data Source Administration or used with connection string via applications or is there a way and if so how?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> Does the "SQL Server" driver that gets installed with the OS get updated via windows updates?

Yes.  Very, very, very rarely.  It's a legacy component, so the bar for changing it is high. It was [updated](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/october-20-2020-kb4580390-os-build-17763-1554-preview-ac4799c9-838f-8665-a968-0f19b6cb1049) in 2020 for the first time in a long time to support TLS 1.2.

Comment: David, this is exactly what I was wondering. It's due to TLS 1.2 but more so towards the removal of TLS 1.1 and TSL 1.0 support. The ODBC definitions can quite easily be changed by dropping and recreating using a driver that supports TLS 1.2. We have apps that use the "SQL Server" driver from within code. I read a post in which someone modified the registry entry of the "SQL Server" driver to point it to a driver that supports TLS 1.2. I'm not that brave. If MS has updated the driver in question as you indicate in your link I will apply and test it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This totally depends upon what that windows patch has bundled within. In our environment we will always apply the patches starting lower environment from DEV QA and UAT before pushing to production.

Generally those windows patch may not impact but in past i have seen windows update some time contain some patch/fixes touching SQL binaries which sort of impacted our sql servers.

Therefore to wrap up i will say test the patch in your staging/test servers and wait for couple of weeks to see how things are behaving from that windows patch.

Comment: KASQLDBA - Thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple SQL Server connection libraries out there

The one for **ODBC** is actively maintained and uses the Control Panel to set up DSNs here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/download-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15

OLE-DB is different. These can be created by creating a txt file and changing the file extension to UDL. You can then play around with the different connection libraries:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/oledb/oledb-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15

The **OLE-DB Provider** is not actively in development and does not support TLS 1.2.

The **Native Client** is also deprecated, but works in a TLS environment

The **OLE-DB Driver** is the only currently supported Windows library from MS and does support TLS 1.2

Here is the download link
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/oledb/release-notes-for-oledb-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15

I have open ticket with MS concerning creating Linked Servers between instances of SQL Server 2019 using the OLE-DB Driver and it throwing certificate chain errors.
After 2 months, they still cant figure it out. If they do, ill update my answer